# Why Haskell doesn't have a single element tuple?

Tags: haskell

I'm wondering why Haskell doesn't have a single element tuple. Is it just because nobody needed it so far, or any rational reasons?  I found an interesting thread in a comment at the Real World Haskell's website http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/types-and-functions.html#funcstypes.composite, and people guessed various reasons like:

- No good syntax sugar.
- It is useless.
- You can think that a normal value like (1) is actually a single element tuple.

But does anyone know the reason except a guess?

Comment: Those three point sound pretty compelling.

Comment: You might just as well ask, why is there no single element tuple in mathematics?

Comment: @luqui there is, and it's called singleton -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple

Comment: See also: the `Only` type constructor provided by at least 2 Haskell database libraries (to distinguish a string to be substituted for a single parameter from a list of chars to be substituted for multiple parameters)

Comment: FWIW, one-tuples are not useless. Compare `instance SomeClass (OneTuple a)` (an instance for all one-element tuples) versus `instance SomeClass a` (an instance for all values). The former case works as intended in the presence another instance `instance SomeClass (a, a)`, but the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 36):

There's a lib for that!

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/OneTuple/0.2.1/doc/html/Data-Tuple-OneTuple.html

Actually, we have a OneTuple we use all the time. It's called Identity, and is now used as the base of standard pure monads in the new mtl:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.2.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Identity.html

And it has an important use! By virtue of providing a type constructor of kind `* -> *`, it can be made an instance (a trival one, granted, though not the *most* trivial) of Monad, Functor, etc., which lets us use it as a base for transformer stacks.

Comment: Now `base` has `Solo`!

Answer (score 12):

The exact reason is because it's totally unnecessary. Why would you need a one-tuple if you can just have its value?

The syntax also tends to be a bit clunky. In Python, you can have one-tuples, but you need a trailing comma to distinguish it from a parenthesized expression:

```
onetuple = (3,)
```

All in all, there's no reason for it. I'm sure there's no "official" reason because the designers of Haskell probably never even considered a single element tuple because it has no use.

I don't know if you were looking for some reasons beyond the obvious, but in this case the obvious answer is the right one.

Comment: Note that a one-tuple would have a different behavior with regard to bottoms: just as `(⊥,⊥) :: (a,b)` is not the same as `⊥ :: (a,b)`, so too would `OneTuple ⊥ :: OneTuple a` be different from `⊥ :: OneTuple a`.  I can't imagine them being useful, mind you, but it's worth noting.  (And Python's syntax would clash with the useful `-XTupleSections`.)

Comment: Thanks, I agree it is useless, but the fact Python has a single tuple would suggest that it is not so obvious design decision. And I wondered if there were any discussions for the matter.

Comment: @Takashi the reason why Python has a one-tuple is because the parser will accept it. It would be more trouble to leave it out

Comment: I believe tuples in python are mutable (I may be wrong).  This makes a python tuple behave as a "reference cell", where this does not apply to Haskell because everything is immutable.

Comment: @luqui: Tuples in Python are *not* mutable.

Comment: @Greg, hmm, interesting.  Can you speculate why they exist?

Comment: @luqui: Why which exists? Certainly tuples exist because it's useful to have an immutable composite type. I suspect 1-tuples (and the 0-tuple `()`) exist for generality and consistency. With Python's dynamic typing, generality of types is useful because you don't always know ahead of time what precise type something is (although you may know it's "a tuple" of some unspecified size). With Haskell's static typing, you *always* know what type something is, so anytime you thought you wanted a 1-tuple you could simply use a scalar instead.

Comment: @luqui In Python, a tuple is basically an immutable list.

Comment: In Python, one-element tuples are useful for many reason. For example a function expects a sequence, and every tuple has a length associated with it.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is not exactly about Haskell semantics, but about the theoretical mathematical elegance of making a value the same as its one-tuple. (So this answer should not be taken as an explanation of the standard behavior expected of a Haskell implementation, because it isn't intended as such.)

In programming languages and [computation models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation#Functional_models) where all functions are [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), such as [lambda-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic), every function has *exactly* one input argument and one output/return value. No more, no less.

When we want a particular function *f* to have more than one input argument – say 3 –, we simulate it under this curried regime by creating a 1-argument function that returns a 2-argument function. Thus, *f x y z = ((f x) y) z*, and *f x* would return a 2-argument function.

Likewise, sometimes we might want to return more than one value from a function. It is not literally possible under this semantics, but we can simulate it by returning a tuple. We can generalize this.

If, for uniformity, we constrain the only return value of any function to be an (n-)tuple, we are able to harmonize some interesting features of the [unit value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type) and of supposedly non-tuple return values with the features of tuples in general, as follows.

Let's adopt as the general syntax of n-tuples the following schema, where *c<sub>i</sub>* is the component with the index *i*:

[image: (c_1, c_2, \dots, c_{n-1}, c_n)]

Notice that n-tuples have delimiting parentheses in this syntax.

Under this schema, how would we represent a 0-tuple? Since it has no components, this degenerate case would be represented like this: **( )**. This syntax precisely coincides with the syntax we adopt to represent the unit value. So, we are tempted to make the unit value the same as a 0-tuple.

What about a 1-tuple? It would have this representation: [image: (c_1)]. Here a syntactical ambiguity would immediately arise: parentheses would be used in the language both as 1-tuple delimiters and as mere grouping of values or expressions. So, in a context where **(v)** appears, a compiler or interpreter would be unsure whether this is a 1-tuple with a component whose value is **v**, or just an isolated value **v** inside superfluous parentheses.

A way to solve this ambiguity is to force a value to be the same as the 1-tuple that would have it as its only component. Not much would be sacrificed, since the only non-empty projection we can perform on a 1-tuple is to obtain its only value.

For this to be consistently enforced, the syntactical consequence is that we would have to relax a bit our former requirement that delimiting parentheses are mandatory for all n-tuples: now they would be optional for 1-tuples, and mandatory for all other values of *n*. (Or we could require all values to be delimited by parentheses, but this would be inconvenient for practical use.)

In summary, under the interpretation that a 1-tuple is the same as its only component value, we could, by making syntactic puns with parentheses, consider all return values of functions in our programming language or computing model as n-tuples: the 0-tuple in the case of the unit type, 1-tuples in the case of ordinary/"atomic" values which we usually don't think of as tuples, and pairs/triples/quadruples/... for other kinds of tuples. This heterodox interpretation is mathematically parsimonious and uniform, is expressive enough to simulate functions with multiple input arguments and multiple return values, and is not incompatible with Haskell (in the sense that no harm is done if the programmer assumes this unofficial interpretation).

This was an argument by syntactic puns. Whether you are satisfied or not with it, we can do even better. A more principled argument can be taken from the [mathematical theory of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation), by exploring the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) operation.

An ([n-adic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adicity)) relation is extensionally [defined](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cartesian_Product#Finite_Cartesian_Product) as a uniform set of (n-)tuples. (This characterization is fundamental to [relational database theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and is therefore important knowledge for professional computer programmers.)

A dyadic relation – a set of pairs (2-tuples) – is a subset of the Cartesian product of 2 sets:
[image: R_2 \subseteq S \times T]. For a [homogeneous relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_relation): [image: R_2 \subseteq S \times S = S^2].

A triadic relation – a set of triples (3-tuples) – is a subset of the Cartesian product of 3 sets:
[image: R_3 \subseteq S \times T \times U]. For a homogeneous relation: [image: R_3 \subseteq S \times S \times S = S^3].

A monadic relation – a set of monuples (1-tuples) – is a subset of the Cartesian product of 1 set:
[image: R_1 \subseteq S = S^1] (by the [usual mathematical convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_products_of_several_sets)).

As we can see, a monadic relation is just a set of atomic values! This means that a set of 1-tuples is a set of atomic values. Therefore, it is convenient to consider that 1-tuples and atomic values are the same thing.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to bring any “mathematical elegance” arguments in here. If tuples express the cartesian product, then `((a,b),c)` and `(a,(b,c))` should be the same type, but they aren't. The whole mathematical backing of Haskell generally holds only “up to isomorphism” and “if we ignore ⊥”. But then you can't make any arguments regarding if 1-tuples should be a thing, because they're anyway isomorphic to the contained type.

Comment: the syntactic ambiguity of `(a)` only arises if you choose to use parenthesis for both tuples and grouping. If one chooses some other syntax--say `[]` for tuples--the ambiguity disappears, without requiring any punning.

Comment: I should mention that `(a, b, c)` syntax for a tuple is actually a syntactic sugar for `a * (b * (c * 1))` where `(*)` is a product type and `1` is a unit type. That's why `((a, b), c)` and `(a, (b, c))` are different types, and why unary tuple `(a) = a * 1` is not the same as `a`: it's a product with a unit. Existence of unique isomorphism to `a` is not the same as equality. You'd think this is only about programming, but Bourbaki's definition of tuple is not much different.